# iOS Enterprise Wireless (OTA) distribution Unable to Download Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, ota, enterprise-distribution

My company has an enterprise ios account and I am hoping to upload my app on it wirelessly. I have been given distribution certificate and distribution provisioning profile by the client.

I followed this great tutorial here on [blog.appliedis.com](http://blog.appliedis.com/2012/10/29/wireless-distribution-of-enterprise-ios-apps/), which shows how to wirelessly deploy the app with enterprise account.

The problem is that I get this error when install the app on iPad, right at the end when the install is about to finish.

> Unable to Download App  MyApp could not be installed at this time

### My Steps

Here are the steps I took:-

- Matched the Bundle ID of the app (in plist) with which client's certificate / provisioning profile is created.
- Clicked/installed Distribution Certificate from the client to my KeyChain
- Dragged Provisioning profile (Distribution) from the client into XCode
- In Code Signing, I selected Distribution certificate (sent by the client) in all of them as shown (notice all have same):-

[image: Code Signing Identities]

and for Provisioning Profiles, I selected distribution Provisioning profile sent by the client as follows (notice both are same):-

[image: Provisioning profile]

- Xcode > Product > Archive > Save For Enterprise Deployment
- Specified the title, URL for IPA on my server.
- Hosted the .ipa, .plist (Both xcode generated) on my Linux server.
- Created a link as follows:- https://www.myurl.com/myapps/MyApp.plist">Click to Download
- When clicked, app starts but slaps the error when app downloading is in the mid way.

### Additional Info:-

- The reason why we opted for iOS Enterprise account is that we don't have to enter UDIDs. So the iPad in which this app is being installed doesn't have its UDID in the client's account.

### Below is my Console Log (Just in case)

```
Aug 19 22:09:30 My-iPad wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[430193370.378140]: Foreground Network Application exited.
Aug 19 22:09:30 My-iPad wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[430193370.378722]: BG Application: Not Present, BG Daemon: Present. Daemons: SiriViewService networkd itunesstored apsd assistantd sharingd 
Aug 19 22:09:30 My-iPad itunesstored[90] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing placeholder for com.theclientname.app
Aug 19 22:09:30 My-iPad installd[63] <Notice>: 0x315000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/-4665319901594503043.app" requested by itunesstored
Aug 19 22:09:30 My-iPad installd[63] <Notice>: 0x315000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.theclientname.app
Aug 19 22:09:30 My-iPad installd[63] <Notice>: 0x315000 install_application: Installing placeholder
Aug 19 22:09:30 My-iPad installd[63] <Notice>: 0x315000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.01s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.05s; LS Sync: 0.00s; Overall: 0.06s
Aug 19 22:09:31 My-iPad itunesstored[90] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:LSApplicationProxy: com.theclientname.app (Placeholder) withPhase:0
Aug 19 22:09:31 My-iPad lsd[73] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Waiting; fractionCompleted=0.000000> to 0
Aug 19 22:10:12 My-iPad SpringBoard[33] <Warning>: Killing com.theclientname.app for app installation
Aug 19 22:10:12 My-iPad itunesstored[90] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder LSApplicationProxy: com.theclientname.app (Placeholder)
Aug 19 22:10:12 My-iPad itunesstored[90] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:LSApplicationProxy: com.theclientname.app (Placeholder) withPhase:1
Aug 19 22:10:12 My-iPad lsd[73] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Active; fractionCompleted=0.590000> to 1
Aug 19 22:10:12 My-iPad installd[63] <Notice>: 0x315000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-4665319901594503043/-8050886506109721064" requested by itunesstored
Aug 19 22:10:17 My-iPad wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[430193417.818493]: Client itunesstored set type to normal application
Aug 19 22:10:17 My-iPad wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[430193417.819443]: BG Application: Not Present, BG Daemon: Present. Daemons: SiriViewService networkd apsd assistantd sharingd 
Aug 19 22:10:17 My-iPad installd[63] <Notice>: 0x315000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.theclientname.app
Aug 19 22:10:17 My-iPad installd[63] <Error>: profile not valid: 0xe8008012
Aug 19 22:10:17 My-iPad installd[63] <Error>: 0x315000 install_embedded_profile: Could not install embedded profile: 0xe8008012
Aug 19 22:10:19 My-iPad installd[63] <Error>: 0x315000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.vSfPbR/foo_extracted/Payload/APPNAME.app/APPNAME: 0xe8008015
Aug 19 22:10:19 My-iPad installd[63] <Error>: 0x315000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.vSfPbR/foo_extracted/Payload/APPNAME.app
Aug 19 22:10:19 My-iPad installd[63] <Error>: 0x315000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
Aug 19 22:10:19 My-iPad itunesstored[90] <Error>: 0x1ac1000 MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices: failed with -1
Aug 19 22:10:19 My-iPad itunesstored[90] <Warning>: ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
Aug 19 22:10:19 My-iPad lsd[73] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation failed for app com.theclientname.app
Aug 19 22:10:19 My-iPad itunesstored[90] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.theclientname.app.Installing - <NSProgress: phase=Installing; state=Failed; fractionCompleted=0.000000> called, removing progress from cache
Aug 19 22:10:19 My-iPad lsd[73] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation failed for app com.theclientname.app
Aug 19 22:10:19 My-iPad itunesstored[90] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.theclientname.app.Loading - <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Failed; fractionCompleted=1.000000> called, removing progress from cache
Aug 19 22:10:19 My-iPad installd[63] <Error>: 0x315000 handle_install_for_ls: API failed
Aug 19 22:10:21 My-iPad assistantd[36] <Notice>: connection 11 total: 1, connected: 0, added new subflow [cid=1, state=Waiting, ifindex=2]
Aug 19 22:10:21 My-iPad assistantd[36] <Notice>: connection 11 total: 1, connected: 1, new connected subflow [cid=1, state=Connected, ifindex=2, preferred, mp_capable]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of potential'gotchas' that you should check. An obvious one, for iOS 7.1 + is that the download html and manifest .plist have to be on an https server. Another is that, even if they are, that server must be correctly handling the MIME type for .ipa files. I think that there's no problem generally with Apache servers. Microsoft servers aren't natively set up for this so they have to be 'tuned' by their administrators to see '.ipa' as "application/octet-stream."

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue with my distribution license, and the problem was there was "XC" provisioning profile which had the exact same bundle id.

My solution to his was to delete this XC: provisioning profile both from Apple Developer Portal and Xcode -> Preferences -> Apple ID -> View Details -> XC: provisioning profile -> right click Go To Finder -> delete

Hope this helps,